# Spliting exact time from MongoDB createdAt field

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have a `MongoDB` collection which contains some data created by users. I want to get exact time from `createdAt` filed. Please see the below image.

[image: mongoDB screenshot]

See the createdAt timestamp for a data created on `2023-08-17 22:30:02`.

I'm building a `next.js` app. I'm able to split date from the timestamp using `slice()` method. But time given here is in some another format. Can anyone help me to get the time in standard format?

Comment: What is the expected output? Have you checked out formatting the date by using [$dateToString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#format-specifiers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some library exist that format you date and time and also make them separate.

1. Dayjs    : [Link](https://day.js.org/)
2. Moment   : [Link](https://momentjs.com/)
3. Luxon    : [Link](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)
4. date-fns : [Link](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started/)

But you can achieve same thing with JavaScript as well.

```
`${new Date('2023-08-17 22:30:02').getHours()}
 :${new Date('2023-08-17 22:30:02').getMinutes()}
 :${new Date('2023-08-17 22:30:02').getSeconds()}`
```

Comment: I was using `timeago`  library. Is there any method available in `react-timeago` library?

Comment: I don't know about  react-timeago 
but I find something like : <TimeAgo date='Feb 1, 1966' formatter={formatter} />
If it's help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you handle the date formatting at server side to avoid potential inconsistent parsing of timezone between client side and server side using `$dateToString`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "createdAtString": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$createdAt",
          "format": "%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S",
          "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lPKAANxJJFT)